# Why doesn't setTimeout return the value I expect?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, settimeout

I want the function "getRandomSave" to return a asyncs value, that's why I'm using a setTimeout, which works just fine in a console but I can't make it return the value that shows in the console.

in the service:

```
  getRandom(length){

    let jsonlength = length
    let a = 0;
    let randomNumber = new Array()


    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
      
      a++

      if (a > jsonlength) {

        this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
        clearInterval(myInterval);

      }else{
         randomNumber.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10))
      }

    },.1)

    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{resolve(randomNumber)}, 1000)
     })
     .then(x =>{return x})

  }
  
    getRandomSave(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            return this.randomNumber
        },200)
    }
```

when execute(in the component):

```
  randomNumber(){ 

    let accesoriosJsonLength:number = this.accesoriosJson.length

    if (this.browserRefresh) {

        this.accesoriosService.getRandom(accesoriosJsonLength)
        .then(valor => console.log(valor))

    }else{
      this.accesoriosService.getRandomSave()
      console.log(this.accesoriosService.getRandomSave()); //undefined
    }
```

}

Comment: Use await, example: `console.log(await this.randomNumber)` (remove `getRandomSave()`)

Comment: I needed to clarify some things, had to edit the question

Comment: The code is really weird. Assuming you want to keep the `getRandomSave()` function then use: `getRandomSave() return await this.randomNumber`

Comment: returns ZoneAwarePromise with value undefined

Comment: Apparently using angular, correct?

Comment: There are some things in your code that don't make sense, like this for example: `return new Promise(...).then(x => return x)`

Comment: When you use a return inside a `then` it is because you want to make a call chain, but you don’t

Comment: What you want to return is the randomNumber in `getRandom()`, correct?

Comment: If yes, If so, transform `getRandom` into an async function and use `await` in the return

Comment: `return await Promise(...)`

Comment: What I want to return is an array with 10 random numbers and then go through it with a foreach, thanks for your help

Comment: `I want the function "getRandomSave" to return a asyncs value` 1. Why though? What's the point? 2. it's not returning anything right now, so logging its call will give you `undefined`. I'm guessing you want to return a Promise? https://jsfiddle.net/s5apeLd2/

Comment: I expressed myself badly, sorry. I don't want it to return an async value, what I want is an array with random numbers. Also I don't need getRandom to return a promise. Your answer was very useful to me, thanks! Can I do the same but without using promise?